# Stopping propagation on multiple hover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, jquery-events, preventdefault

My home page contains multiple boxes.

On each boxes, when `mouseover` in or out , the title disappears and the content appears.

It works fine.

The problem is that when mouseovering more than one box on a short period of time, it is a mess.

```
$( ".views-field-wrapper" ).each(function(){         
    $( this ).hover(function() {        
        $( "#front_panel",this ).fadeOut(400);
        $( "#back_panel",this ).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);        
      }, function(){           
        $( "#back_panel",this ).fadeOut(400);
        $( "#front_panel",this ).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

How can I stop the previous `mouseover` reaction when mouseovering another box?

EDIT :

My intial code: http://jsfiddle.net/tz3d6ct6/

Kumar's code that works perfectly with jquery > 1.6 (I must use jquery1.4) http://jsfiddle.net/hrkf5p7w/

Comment: Please use a JSFiddle for visual problems. Also, try using `stop()` to stop prior animations :)

Comment: Also, this could be easily accomplished using CSS3 animations and the `:hover` state, which takes away any of the errors you might encounter and could get a speed boost from the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) and no need to use loop to bind `hover event`,

```
$( ".views-field-wrapper" ).hover(function() { // no need to use each loop
        $( "#front_panel",this ).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
        $( "#back_panel",this ).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    }, function(){
        $( "#back_panel",this ).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
        $( "#front_panel",this ).delay(500).fadeIn(1000);    
});
```

Try it without using using `delay()` like,

```
$(".views-field-wrapper").hover(function () { // no need to use each loop
    $("#front_panel", this).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $("#back_panel", this).fadeIn(1000);

}, function () {
    $("#back_panel", this).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $("#front_panel", this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```js
$(".views-field-wrapper").hover(function () { // no need to use each loop
    $("#front_panel", this).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $("#back_panel", this).fadeIn(1000);
    
}, function () {
    $("#back_panel", this).stop(true).fadeOut(400);
    $("#front_panel", this).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='views-field-wrapper type-t nodetype-t'>
    <div id='front_panel'>title</div>
    <div style='display:none' id='back_panel'>teaser</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx it is much better but if i go too quick on different boxes, some boxes behave weirdly and remain permanentely fadeout entirely or partially. any explanation?

Comment: @Matoeil : Again: As it is a *visual problem*, a JSFiddle would help demonstrate. :)

Comment: i cannot reproduce the weird effect !? this works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/kkq64ao1/

Comment: Yes, it is beacause you used `delay()` when you hover then back_panel fades-in with delay but immediately you mouseout from your element and it will not seen properly. See my working demo for it http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/kkq64ao1/1/

Comment: @Matoeil: You need to save output HTML (not PHP) to the JSFiddle :) Use save-as from your browser and try again :)

Comment: the jsfiddle i provide with your initial code work perfectly with jquery 1.8

Comment: but i found out that jquery 1.6 reproduce the bug i have, can u have a look? ( my drupal site is on jquery 1.4.4 and i dont think i can change that )

Comment: Yes, it is not working properly in `jquery 1.6.*`. You can add latest version of jquery in drupal also. You just need to use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict immediately after using it.

Comment: @Rohan Kumar thanx a lot , i look at this after lunch :)

Comment: To add jquery see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28743/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-the-latest-version-of-jquery-to-a-theme

Comment: i have used the jquery update module and i did not see any side effect yet on other site functionnalitites . thanks for your help kumar